# Does StreamInsight have a future?

Tags: complex-event-processing, streaminsight

We just finished a small project with the primary aim of giving Microsoft StreamInsight a try.

The technology looks fine, but I have a concern about its industry traction. When we ran into issues there were only a handful of materials on the web and generally I miss a vibrant community around it.

Should we expand our use of StreamInsight or it will go down the drain in a few years like Silverlight did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was at a SQL user group meeting about three months ago. I asked that exact question of the speaker (Microsoft Blue Badge). He didn't make a definitive statement but from what he did say it was clear he thought StreamInsight had a big future.

Answer (score 4):

My opinion: it won't go the way of Silverlight. 
Silverlight was, essentially, replaced by other technologies - specifically, HTML 5. StreamInsight doesn't have that. You are correct in that there isn't a whole lot around it. But that is because it's a relatively new technology that has a radically different paradigm, isn't very well known and has more limited use cases than something like ASP.NET MVC. But CEP is an initiative not just from Microsoft (with StreamInsight) but also Oracle, IBM and others. And as data volumes continue to increase, these technologies will be even more important.